# AWS Lambda Python 3.11: Cannot import lxml: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, arm, lxml

I have a Python function on AWS Lambda that depends on `lxml`. The dependent layer includes the result of `poetry install lxml`, yet I receive the following error at runtime:

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app.dim.application.watchdog': libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
```

I have checked the Python 3.11 base image, and it doesn't include `libxslt.so.1`:

`docker run -ti --rm --entrypoint bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11`

How can I include all shared libraries that packages, like `lxml`, depend on? Can I say to `pip` or `poetry` that they should include them in the installed package? It's a nightmare to selectively copy each shared library into a layer.

**Runtime**: Python 3.11

**Architecture**: ARM64

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent a day on this and I've tried all the suggestions I could find online, including:

- building in an EC2 image
- downloading binary packages like suggested by @bbayles
- using the CDK alpha for Python

None of that works, as none of those solutions will include the shared libraries. The problem is not quite in lxml, but in the fact that it has a dependency on `libxml2` and `libxslt`, which are often available in other distributions but not in the Amazon Linux distributions that back lambdas. It cannot be solved by pip, because those libraries are not under pip's control.

The one thing that DOES work is building your own Docker image for the lambda, which includes all needed packages.

A good starting point is [AWS's doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-instructions) on using container images, but see below for an easier option to build and deploy.

Assuming this directory structure:

```
build_dir
|Dockerfile
|requirements.txt
|src
   |lambda.py
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11-arm64
RUN yum -y upgrade
RUN yum -y install python3.11 python3-pip gcc python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel

COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    
COPY src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "lambda.handler" ]
```

Note that you want to ensure that `src` is properly local to the working directory and not a symlink. See this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

requirements.txt. Make sure to add any other packages you will need:

```
lxml
```

lambda.py:

```
import json
import lxml.etree as etree

def handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from LXML!')
    }
```

You need to build the image and deploy the lambda from there. You can  follow the instructions linked above, but if you are using CDK it's much simpler:

within cdk.ts

```
const fn = new cdk.aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "DockerLambda", {
    // Point to the directory where you have Dockerfile
    code: cdk.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("build_dir"),
    // This should not be needed, but there are some issues on mac M1
    architecture: Architecture.ARM_64,
});
```

When you deploy the stack, this will do all the magic: build the image, upload it to a registry, and deploy the lambda.

Comment: Thank you, Anna! I will look at it later. The solution for me was to downgrade to an earlier version of `lxml`. In particular, you want a wheel that's tagged like `manylinux`. This means, it's suitable as-is to be run on any popular Linux distro. By the time I asked this, the `lxml` v4.9.3 only had a source distribution for arm64, which meant it was compiled and dynamically linked against dependencies not present in the Lambda runtime :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid layers, you can create a .zip deployment package for your application that includes all dependencies.

You will want to write a setup script ([reference](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html)) that allows your package to be built locally.

You will also want to write a [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) with pinned dependencies (to ensure reproducible builds).

Once that's done (i.e., you can do `pip install .` from your project directory), you can package everything with the following Makefile:

```
PACKAGE_DIR = /tmp/YOUR_APP_NAME
PACKAGE_ZIP = your_app_name.zip

.PHONY: package
package:
    rm -rf "${PACKAGE_DIR}"
    mkdir -p "${PACKAGE_DIR}"
    rm -f "${PACKAGE_DIR}/../${PACKAGE_ZIP}"
    pip install \
        --quiet \
        --python-version "3.11" \
        --platform "manylinux1_x86_64" \
        --platform "manylinux_2_17_x86_64" \
        --platform "manylinux_2_28_x86_64" \
        --only-binary ":all:" \
        --target "${PACKAGE_DIR}" \
        -r "requirements/base.txt" \
        .
    (cd ${PACKAGE_DIR}; find ./ -type f -name '*.pyc' -delete && find ./ -type d -name '__pycache__' -delete;)
    (cd ${PACKAGE_DIR}; zip -9 -q -r ../${PACKAGE_ZIP} .;)
```

`make package` will produce a zip file suitable for uploading to Lambda. It prefers binary versions of the packages, so you can build on Windows or Mac OS (though if one of your dependencies doesn't have a Linux binary, you'll need to build one).

Comment: Thank you, but how does this fix my issues or `lxml`  shared objects referencing e.g. `libxslt.so.1` on the host system?

Comment: By downloading the binary package from pip, you'll get the necessary library in the lxml wheel.

Comment: Do you know whether this is possible with Poetry? When I run `ldd` on the shared objects in the installed lxml package, they depend on `libxslt.so.1`. What you're saying is that if I install a binary wheel, I get a wheel that includes `libxslt.so.1`?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Serverless Framework with the serverless-python-requirements plugin to build my AWS Lambda package. It was giving me the following error: "Error: Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed."

To resolve the issue, I upgraded to lxml 5.1.0 from 4.9.3 and lxml was built successfully within my package.